# PHP & MySQL striplashes() question

Tags: php, mysql

If `magic_quotes_gpc` is on will I still need to use `striplashes()` if no why? is so when and where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gpc in `magic_quotes_gpc` stands for GET, POST, COOKIE. So everything in `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` got escaped. If magic_quotes_gpc is turned on, you should run stripslashes on variables in those arrays.

Remember to run `mysql_real_escape_string()` on variables in queries (except for prepared statements)

magic_quotes are deprecated, it's recommended to disable it and escape variables using `mysql_real_escape_string()` (for MySQL). Put the following in a .htaccess file for disabling magic_quotes_gpc:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime off
```

Answer (score 0):

Not "still" but that's the only case when you will need this function.

In the configuration file which being included in all your scripts. Strip slashes from all GPC data.

Answer (score 0):

The very good ptactice is make `mysql_real_escape_string()`;
I am advise you to off magic_quotes. In PHP 6 magic quotes will be off.
If your hoster doesn't give you access to change this option, you can use the next function:

```
function stripslashes_deep($value) {
    $value = is_array($value) ?
                array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
}

if((function_exists("get_magic_quotes_gpc") && get_magic_quotes_gpc())    || (ini_get('magic_quotes_sybase') && (strtolower(ini_get('magic_quotes_sybase'))!="off")) ){
    stripslashes_deep($_GET);
    stripslashes_deep($_POST);
    stripslashes_deep($_COOKIE);
}
```